# Formatting a date javascript without ui jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a report, the report has a input of type date that always is going to have the today's date.

I tried someting like this

```
let date = new Date();
$('#fecha').val(date.toISOString()); //fecha is my input
```

It put something like this in the input

2019-08-20T10:51

But I just want to show the date without time. I dont want to add ui Jquery plugin to my project.

Comment: it isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: how not? [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) does everything you want

Comment: Take a look at [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like below,

```
let date = new Date();
$('#fecha').val(date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate());
```